# Unit test gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I'm trying to write a unit test case for the handler.sendRequest(request); function. However, it returns the null pointer exception.
When I print the request object in the unit test it returns null. However, I have initialized the request object not sure why it is giving null pointer exception. Is something wrong with the Data object? Have I missed something? Can someone please help? Thanks!

```java
public class ServicesHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Mock
    private AuthHandler AuthHandler;

    @InjectMocks
    ServicesHandler handler;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() throws Exception {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());  
        data.setRequestedQuantity(10);

        Request request = new Request();
        request.setData(data );

        System.out.println("request = " + request);
        ServicesHandler handler = new ServicesHandler();
        Mockito.when(AuthHandler.requestToken()).thenReturn("randomString");
Mockito.when(msAuthHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders("randomString")).thenReturn(any());
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK));
        handler.sendRequest(request);
    }
```

```java
 @Component
 public class ServicesHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Value("${api.host}")
    private String msApiHost;

    @Value("${base.path}")
    private String BasePath;

    @Autowired
    private AuthHandler authHandler;

    public AuthHandler getAuthHandler() {
        return authHandler;
    }



   public ResponseEntity<String> sendRequest(Request pr) throws Exception {
    
   ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

        try {
            String requestToken = getAuthHandler().requestToken();

            HttpHeaders headers = getAuthHandler().createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders(requestToken);
            
            String apiUrl = ApiHost + BasePath;

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

        HttpEntity<Request> request = new HttpEntity<Request>(pr, headers);
            response = restTemplate.postForEntity(apiUrl, request, String.class);
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            logger.error("Error when sending for provisioning " + e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return response;
   }
 }
```

```java
public class Data {
    private String requestId;
    private Integer requestedQuantity;

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public Integer getRequestedQuantity() {
        return requestedQuantity;
    }

    public void setRequestedQuantity(Integer requestedQuantity) {
        this.requestedQuantity = requestedQuantity;
    }
}
```

It gives me an error in `getAuthHandler().requestToken();` function inside `handler.sendRequest(request);`

Below is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.xyz.abc.sendRequest(ServicesHandler.java:443) at com.xyz.abc.ServicesHandlerTest.testSuccess(ServicesHandlerTest.java:150) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: You create mocks, create a new instance of the handler but don't inject the mocks into the handler.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your reply. Could you please help me to understand How does inject mock into handler help or how can I do that?

Comment: After using @InjectMocks still the same error. Kindly assist me to fix what is missing.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.xyz.abc.sendRequest(ServicesHandler.java:443)
 at com.xyz.abc.ServicesHandlerTest.testSuccess(ServicesHandlerTest.java:150)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: Please add it to your question, properly formatted not as comment as that is totally unreadale.

Comment: Please add a proper stacktrace (and the fullone) the current is one long line which isn't really readable.

Comment: Your test doesn't setup the call to `createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders` which will return `null` (the default for a mock). Next to that your code is flawed, you should inject a pre-configured instance of a `RestTEmplate` not construct one because you need it (it is a quite heavy operation and will slow down your code).

Comment: Itried```Mockito.when(AuthHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders(any())).thenReturn(any()); ``` call to ```createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders``` does not work. How can I inject a pre-configured instance of RestTemplate?

Comment: What am I missing in ```Mockito.when(authHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders("randomString")).thenReturn(any());``` Kindly assist me to fix the same. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Hi @SwetaSharma as Deinum already pointed you should not create instance of `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` and `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();` as like this, you should Autowire them like how you did for `private AuthHandler authHandler;`

Comment: @Deadpool Sure, Will autowire RestTemplate and ObjectMapper. I need your help in  ``` Mockito.when(AuthHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders("randomString")).thenReturn(any()); ``` Is it correct or I missed something?

Comment: That is wrong, you should return `HttpHeaders` like this ```Mockito.when(AuthHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders("randomString")).thenReturn(new HttpHeaders());```  @SwetaSharma

Comment: @Deadpool I have mock AuthHandler however it still gives me error  ``` 
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
at   ``` Mockito.when(AuthHandler.createAuthorizationBearerHttpHeaders("randomString")).thenReturn(new HttpHeaders());   ``` What have I missed in the mocking? Could you please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

You should inject the mocks into `ServicesHandler` using `@InjectMocks`, see the docs for more information [MockitoAnnotations.initMocks](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object))

```
public class ServicesHandlerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServicesHandler;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Mock
    private AuthHandler AuthHandler;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() throws Exception {
         Data data = new Data();
         data.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());  
         data.setRequestedQuantity(10);

         Request request = new Request();
         request.setData(data );

         System.out.println("request = " + request);
    
    
   Mockito.when(AuthHandler.requestToken()).thenReturn("randomString");
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK));
    handler.sendRequest(request);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried @Injectmocks However, it still gives me a null pointer exception. Could you please assist me If I missed something.

Comment: Have I missed something with the requestToken?

Comment: You forgot to use a runner, like @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Comment: @Milgo I added ```@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)``` still the same error.

Comment: @Milgo Just curious to know. What is the need of adding runner?